# Constant save file directory

Tags: c#, filepath

I have a VS2012 in C# solution with 4 projects in 4 layer structure(Presentation, BusinessLogic, DomainModel, DataAccess) and wanted to give the user the option to select the database's file's path at the Login form, which is in the Presentation layer (it is then used when a creating connection to the Database in a static method in the DataAccess layer). And the path would be saved and used the next time the application runs.

A bit more workflow example would be:

1. User starts the application and the login form appears;
2. User chooses the Database's file path with a FolderBrowserDialog or
   OpenDirectoryDialog;
3. User works on the application then ends it;
4. User starts the application and the Database's file path is the one
   he picked before;
5. User works on the application then ends it;
6. User starts the application and picks another file;
7. User works on the application then ends it;
8. User starts the application and the Database's file path is the one
   he picked before.

Codewise I don't want to go passing along that string (path) all around my code for each method that needs to create a connection and such.

So any ideas on how to directly save it in the method that's directly using it? If not only when the user wants to change it then just forcing the user to pick the file when the starts the application.

Currently what I'm doing is forcing the user to put the file he wants in the solution's directory with a specific name before starting the application when he wants to use another Database file. For that I'm using:

```
    public static string path;
    public static OleDbConnection createConnection()
    {
        path = DirProject() + "\\Calibrações Equipamentos ULSM.accdb";
        OleDbConnectionStringBuilder builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
        builder["Provider"] = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
        builder["Data Source"] = path;

        return new OleDbConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
    }

    private static string DirProject()
    {
        string DirDebug = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        string DirProject = DirDebug;

        for (int counter_slash = 0; counter_slash < 3; counter_slash++)
        {
            DirProject = DirProject.Substring(0, DirProject.LastIndexOf(@"\"));
        }

        return DirProject;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration (=data) is **not** saved into a method (=code). It's usually saved into a configuration file. You can leverage [.NET's application and user settings mechanism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use  User Settings

[How To: Write User Settings at Run Time with C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[How To: Read Settings at Run Time With C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397759%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)